# Is Window Workflow Foundation AOP?

Tags: workflow-foundation, aop

I am new in Window Workflow Foundation and AOP. I found that they are quite similar. So I am wondering that WWF is AOP... I know the concept of WWF is different from AOP. However, I think they are going to achieve the similar idea.

If this is a silly question, I am so sorry. Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think no - those ideas are different.

AOP idea is to develop cleaner code, better encapsulate it, make systems less coupled and easier to maintain. It is an idea targeted mainly on developers.

WWF idea is to assemble enterprise applications from pre-built blocks. Targeted somewhere in between developers and business analytics. With WWF you can possibly re-use some modules in new contexts, but generally WWF tries to resemble concepts of [business process modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_modeling).

Of course, you can imagine a lot of situations where you can use WWF as the tool to achieve better encapsulation and loose coupling or otherwise - to use AOP to re-use modules and organise it in a workflow. But the intersection of their general ideas is rather small.